# Using find grep together

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to make a command to get all the files from the current folder and it's subtree that ends with a suffix then them need to contain lines which start's  with a capital letter and and with !. I spent some to find a solution. I only found how to print the lines which starts with capital character but i don't know how to put in the command that '!'.

This is to find all the files which contains a line starting with a capital letter. How do i add to look for lines which ends with !.

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l "^[A-Z]+*" {} +
```

Comment: What may appear between the capital letter and the exclamation mark? Anything?

Comment: Anything. Just to start with a capital character and to end with ! ( the line)

Comment: Then the pattern should be `^[A-Z].*!$` (if capital letter means A-Z).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex in `grep`:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -El '^[[:blank:]]*[A-Z].*![[:blank:]]*$' {} +
```

Comment: Still not working my file contest is something line this "Ahhhhhhhh!" this is a line

Comment: So you have double quotes also in your file after `!` ?

Comment: No no Ahhhhhh! is the line. I am so noob with this reg exp

Comment: In that case above `find` works fine and I've tested it as well. Make sure you copy paste exact full command line from here. Also make sure there are no hidden characters. check with `cat -vte file` to see all characters on that input file

Comment: Thank you. The problem was i used a file made in dos. Thank you a lot.

Comment: One more thing. Can you explain me please what [[:blank:]] does and if they always need to be used like this?

Comment: `[[:blank:]]` matches whitespace. So, lines starting with spaces or tabs (0 or more times) and then a capital letter will match.  Same for the end, whitespace after the ! is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Following syntax will be useful. If am getting the question right this is the solution for you:

```
find . -type f -name '*!.*' -exec grep -l "^[A-Z]+*" {} +
```

Comment: it says -bash: ! event not found

Comment: do the files have extentions? like Abc!.txt or something like this?

Comment: Use the updated commend it should resolved your query

Comment: First i need to find the files then i need to print only certain files using grep. Rules for grep are to contatin a line starting with a capital character and ending with !.

Comment: find command is ok. Grep is wrong. Let's say find . -type -f name '*.txt' -exec -grep -l "^[A-Z+*?????here is the thing i don't know to look for ! at the end of line"

Comment: This signifacntly does what you ask of it.

Comment: @UsamaZafar I'm fairly sure OP is looking for `!` *inside* the file, not as part of the name.

Answer (score 0):

`find . -type f -name '*suffix' -print0 | xargs -r0 grep -le '^[A-Z].*!$'` should do what you want.

It `find`s all files (`-type f`) with a suffixed name (`-name '*suffix'`) and feeds those files to `grep` using `xargs`.  The regular expression then finds lines that begin with a capital and end with an exclamation mark.

The problem here is mostly quoting.  The `!` is special in bash (and other shells) and refers to the history.  You need to escape it, either by using single quotes or escaping it, by prepending a backslash.

Comment: Why `-name`? Why `xargs`?

Comment: `-name` because he wants to match files that have a suffix; `xargs` because I think it's more easy to read and understand, considering quoting you may or may not have to do with `-exec`.

Comment: Ah, missed the suffix part. Still don't see the benefit of `xargs`, but to each their own.

Comment: I agree it doesn't have a real benefit in terms of anything, other than readability (again, IMO).  `-exec ... {} +` does pretty much the same as `xargs`.